# glob()-like C function however supporting the "**"-recursive syntax?

Tags: recursion, filesystems, posix, glob, directory-listing

I've just noticed that passing e.g.: `**/main.c` to POSIX function `glob()` doesn't yield correct results (they are empty). Is there a similar and also such a common (POSIX, etc.) function that would support the "**"-recursive syntax? Or maybe some single file, small library with such feature?